# Is there efficient way of providing create external table statement in aws athena cli command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-athena

I'm working on Agile methodology project with EMR as the processing engine, AWS Athena with Tableu as the presentation layer and S3 as storage layer. Is there a way to provide create table file names in the aws athena cli command mode?

So far, I tried the below two options that are not efficient or don't work as expected.

1.Manually creating the external tables through the AWS console whenever a new addition field is requested or new table added.
2.Tried the below but didn't work
export ATHENA_EXT_TABLE_1_SETUP=$(sed 's/${env:EXPORT_LOCATION}/$EXPORT_LOCATION/g' hive/ext/table_1_setup.q | envsubst)

"Name": "setup athena tables",
    "Args": [
      "aws",
      "athena",
      "start-query-execution",
      "--query-string",
      "$ATHENA_EXT_TABLE_1_SETUP",
      "--query-execution-context",
      " Database=reporting",
      "--result-configuration",
      "OutputLocation=$ATHENA_LOCATION"
   ]
put the above in a json file and call it through the aws command line jar file but since the create external table statement is so big, the variable ATHENA_EXT_TABLE_1_SETUP is not able to hold the entire string to be added as part of the EMR cluster steps

aws emr add-steps --cluster-id $CLUSTER_ID --steps "$(cat hive/ext/table_setup.json | envsubst)"

All our create external table setup's are stored in files, one for each table and EMR is transient cluster. We run the setup scripts at the beginning of EMR start up process and make external files available for processing. I want to make use of external table set up files to be used to create tables in Athena as well, I am looking for some command in Athena that looks similar to the hive and below

hive -f  "/home/hadoop/hive/ext/table_1_setup.q"

This will help us to do the setup in Athena as part of CI/CD process otherwise, we need to this manually every time.

I wonder why AWS didn't give the option of providing file as input in the aws cli query-string

aws athena start-query-execution --query-string {value}

Is there a way to provide  to be read from a file?